# Search robots can't index because of assets present rails heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-search-console

On these websites https://staging.blockbutler.io and https://blockbutler.io (RoR on heroku both)
Google and Yandex search bots can't index with reason: 'robots.txt blocks'
but robots.txt is fine. And if you will remove 
`javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` it perfectly indexed the page. I spent 3 days of trying different tests - nothing helps:

1. if there are only `javascript_include_tag` with empty
   application.js or only `stylesheet_link_tag` with empty
   application.scss - no indexing
2. add `gem 'rails_12factor'` - no
   indexing
3. `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and push static files from public/assets to server - no indexing
4. put assets in footer - no indexing
5. wrap assets in `<noindex>` and `rel: "nofollow"` - no indexing

I really don't know what da magic is going on and be really happy for any ideas

Logs when run google search console live test:
[image]

production.rb:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.compile = true
```

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /

User-agent: Google
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://blockbutler.io/sitemap.xml
```

p.s. sorry for bad english - will appreciate editing my language (:

Answer (score 0):

Some freaking magic over here.
Change `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', rel: "nofollow" %>` to `<script src="/assets/application.js" rel="nofollow"></script>`

And now google indexer works just fine. GooGLe InDExER DoesN'T LiKE BIg fiLe NamES. Will think about how to prevent cache assets file.

p.s. ok. Now every time Im updating assets - Im changing assets name, like applicationv0.js and etc. Still have no idea, why google wasn't ok with default application-hash.js filename